# BarCodeURL image size

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to generate a barcode through the BarCodeURL AMPScript function ( http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/barcodeurl/#BarCodeURL )

The problem is that, whatever width I use as parameter, the image and the actual barcode inside it do not have the expected sizes. The barcode is larger only when I reach 1000 pixel width. See examples below:

200px width - BarCodeURL(coupon,'Code128B', 200, 100, 0,1,'',0,1)
image width is 451px, barcode is 7,6 cm
http://cl.S7.exct.net/LiveContent.aspx?qs=b8ce8745bcf37960b0d908175fd4f5e102249277b2f27693e3f7816a18b005c836e353418e7d036d10479f8bb7d8f69c082b936c23edb80eaa607fe1524e83281e01d6e1a07de1552f8b1e2df85095b627e73bdc867437b9ee6713bce76737078a51dbc2ae802b82b258ec74ef5174b087d346fdfdcc448a

400px width - BarCodeURL(coupon,'Code128B', 400, 100, 0,1,'',0,1)
image width is 451px, barcode is 7,6 cm
http://cl.S7.exct.net/LiveContent.aspx?qs=b8ce8745bcf37960b0d908175fd4f5e102249277b2f27693e3f7816a18b005c836e353418e7d036d10479f8bb7d8f69c082b936c23edb80eaa607fe1524e83281e01d6e1a07de1552f8b1e2df85095b618c0466292685f29b4c246a5dbbe61e2c21ccc7f55c6041b87cb935a969563a47bcf0cca20e3e039

500px width - BarCodeURL(coupon,'Code128B', 500, 100, 0,1,'',0,1)
image width is 500px, barcode is 7,6 cm
http://cl.S7.exct.net/LiveContent.aspx?qs=b8ce8745bcf37960b0d908175fd4f5e102249277b2f27693e3f7816a18b005c836e353418e7d036d10479f8bb7d8f69c082b936c23edb80eaa607fe1524e83281e01d6e1a07de1552f8b1e2df85095b6089ca5d7175110d4fb1da91af34d0ba81d3372eb3ff845150963bf6a81888d5b213a07afc9c8f0ba

1000px width - BarCodeURL(coupon,'Code128B', 1000, 100, 0,1,'',0,1)
image width is 1000px, barcode is 15,2 cm
http://cl.S7.exct.net/LiveContent.aspx?qs=b8ce8745bcf37960b0d908175fd4f5e102249277b2f27693e3f7816a18b005c836e353418e7d036d10479f8bb7d8f69c082b936c23edb80eaa607fe1524e83281e01d6e1a07de1552f8b1e2df85095b6fef6991b224f2a8ed3db46eaecd2719827c04a387f9661ebf75ac856991713ff35a7e4e03c9d0f47

Thank you

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your reply, but I did not get it. I am able to open the barcodes links above from a new browser private window and even from my mobile phone (different network indeed). What do you mean you need credentials? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not mirror the barcode width in your `img` tag -- as shown on the wiki page?

```
<img width="400" src="%%=BarCodeURL(coupon,'Code128B',400,100,0,1,'',0,1)=%%"/>

<img width="400" src="http://cl.S7.exct.net/LiveContent.aspx?qs=b8ce8745bcf37960b0d908175fd4f5e102249277b2f27693e3f7816a18b005c836e353418e7d036d10479f8bb7d8f69c082b936c23edb80eaa607fe1524e83281e01d6e1a07de1552f8b1e2df85095b618c0466292685f29b4c246a5dbbe61e2c21ccc7f55c6041b87cb935a969563a47bcf0cca20e3e039"/>
```

[image]